# How connect variable with a string in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script , I used 1 variable in my bash file like below

```
list=`/home/ea/students'
```

I wrote below link in my bash but I got error

```
cat $list /admin.txt
```

Do you know how can I connect variable and string together?

Comment: For starters, you're using two different style quotes in your list definition, which tend to mean very different things.

Comment: For future reference,  including the error message in your post is more useful to those trying to help than, "I got error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you need to use single quotes ('`'`') around strings, not backticks ('`')

```
list='/home/ea/students'
```

To append a string to a variable, do the following:

```
list=${list}/admin.txt
```

Demo:

```
echo $list
/home/ea/students/admin.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list='/home/ea/students'
...
cat "${list}/admin.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go with either:

```
cat "$list/admin.txt"
```

In this case the braces '{}' are not mandatory
as the / is not a valid identifier name character.

... or, if you need a variable, recent *bash* versions provide more concise way for *appending*:

```
bash-4.1$ list=/home/ea/students
bash-4.1$ list+=/admin.txt
bash-4.1$ printf '%s\n' "$list"
/home/ea/students/admin.txt
```